# How can I exclude a frame from the theme?

Tags: beamer

I have to use the university default title page for my presentation, but the theme, "Singapore", is imposing on this

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to exclude the title page from the theme?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

... %packages%

%% Title slide formatting %%

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{titlebackground}{images/title-slide-background.png}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(-28.5,-163){%
            \pgfuseimage{titlebackground}
        }
        \put(0,-75){%
            \begin{minipage}[b][4.5cm][t]{0.5\textwidth}
                \color{white}
                \usebeamerfont{title}
                    {\inserttitle\\[0.9cm]}
                \usebeamerfont{subtitle}
                    {\insertauthor\par}
                    {\insertinstitute\\[0.3cm]}
                    {\insertdate}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{picture}
}



%% General slide formatting %%

\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{4,30,66}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.9cm]{oxfordlogo}{images/oxford-logo.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=1cm]{mathslogo}{images/mathematics-logo.png}



\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}

{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(-8,-10){%
            \color{blue}\insertframetitle
        }
        \put(-7,-20){%
            \tiny\color{oxfordblue}\insertframesubtitle
        }
    \end{picture}
}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

%% Information (author, title, etc.) %%

\title[Short version of title]{Scattering \& blow-up phenomena for semi-linear wave equations} % short title for footer
\author%
{%
    \sc{Author: Edmund A. Paxton}\\
   \newline \sc{Supervisor: Prof. Luc Nguyen} \newline
}
\institute%
{%
    \textit{Mathematical Institute}\\
    \textit{University of Oxford}
}
\date[PoM2015]{CDT summer project report, September 2016} % short date for footer





\begin{document}

%% Content of slides %%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all "theme"-elements like headline or footline by using a `plain` from for the title page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

%% Title slide formatting %%

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{titlebackground}{example-image}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(-28.5,-163){%
            \pgfuseimage{titlebackground}
        }
        \put(0,-75){%
            \begin{minipage}[b][4.5cm][t]{0.5\textwidth}
                \color{white}
                \usebeamerfont{title}
                    {\inserttitle\\[0.9cm]}
                \usebeamerfont{subtitle}
                    {\insertauthor\par}
                    {\insertinstitute\\[0.3cm]}
                    {\insertdate}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{picture}
}



%% General slide formatting %%

\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{4,30,66}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.9cm]{oxfordlogo}{example-image}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=1cm]{mathslogo}{example-image}



\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(-8,-10){%
            \color{blue}\insertframetitle
        }
        \put(-7,-20){%
            \tiny\color{oxfordblue}\insertframesubtitle
        }
    \end{picture}
}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

%% Information (author, title, etc.) %%

\title[Short version of title]{Scattering \& blow-up phenomena for semi-linear wave equations} % short title for footer
\author%
{%
    \sc{Author: Edmund A. Paxton}\\
   \newline \sc{Supervisor: Prof. Luc Nguyen} \newline
}
\institute%
{%
    \textit{Mathematical Institute}\\
    \textit{University of Oxford}
}
\date[PoM2015]{CDT summer project report, September 2016} % short date for footer


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Offtopic:**

You should try to avoid formatting commands like `\newline` in the argument commands such as `\author`. As you are already using defining your own version of the title page, include such formatting stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code didn't compile, but try using

```
{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \maketitle
}
```

This locally sets the `footline` and `headline` templates as empty.

A trimmed down version of your code is below. Note that `\sc` has been deprecated for a couple of decades, `\scshape` should be used instead. In addition, both of them are switches, not commands that take an argument, so I rewrote it as `{\scshape Author: ....}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

%% Information (author, title, etc.) %%

\title[Short version of title]{Scattering \& blow-up phenomena for semi-linear wave equations} % short title for footer
\author%
{%
    {\scshape Author: Edmund A. Paxton
   \newline Supervisor: Prof. Luc Nguyen} \newline
}
\institute%
{%
    \textit{Mathematical Institute}\\
    \textit{University of Oxford}
}
\date[PoM2015]{CDT summer project report, September 2016} % short date for footer





\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \maketitle
}
\section{Intro?}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Something}
ABC
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```